# ModelMapper failed to convert java.util.List to java.util.List

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I tried to convert a @Entity into a DTO using ModelMapper, so i got this error:

```
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.CollectionConverter@f3e6876 failed to convert java.util.List to java.util.List.

1 error
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: .....so the error you're getting is that you cannot convert from a Data Type to the same Data Type?

Comment: We will need to see more than the error messages you've provided to be able to tell you what is happening.  Where is your source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the real problem was:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.backapi.aviso.domain.Aviso.links, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Resolved with:
`@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: Got this exception too. And indeed that was the root cause.